# Не загружается игра в Instant Games Facebook. Как решить проблему?

Tags: c#, unity3d, facebook

Я выкладываю игру с Unity в Facebook. Прошел регистрацию, вошел в аккаунт разработчика (facebook for developers - далее ffd). Но у меня крутится вечная загрузка, и я не знаю как это исправить. Причем на заднем фоне, за загрузкой, проходит загрузка от Unity и игра запускается (но загрузка от facebook перекрывает).

Игру я компилирую под WEBGL, папку архивирую и прикрепляю к Веб хостингу в ffd - все по официальной документации. В консоли:

> Blocked opening  in a new window because the request was made in
> a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Смысл ошибки в целом понимаю, но не знаю, как и где ее исправлять. Саму аутентификацию делаю таким образом:

```
// Import statements introduce all the necessary classes for this example.
using Facebook.Unity;
using PlayFab;
using PlayFab.ClientModels;
using UnityEngine;
using LoginResult = PlayFab.ClientModels.LoginResult;

public class PlayfabFacebookAuthExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    // holds the latest message to be displayed on the screen
    private string _message;

    public void Start()
    {
        SetMessage("Initializing Facebook..."); // logs the given message and displays it on the screen using OnGUI method

        // This call is required before any other calls to the Facebook API. We pass in the callback to be invoked once initialization is finished
        FB.Init(OnFacebookInitialized);

    }

    private void OnFacebookInitialized()
    {
        SetMessage("Logging into Facebook...");

        // Once Facebook SDK is initialized, if we are logged in, we log out to demonstrate the entire authentication cycle.
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
            FB.LogOut();

        // We invoke basic login procedure and pass in the callback to process the result
        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(null, OnFacebookLoggedIn);
    }

    private void OnFacebookLoggedIn(ILoginResult result)
    {
        // If result has no errors, it means we have authenticated in Facebook successfully
        if (result == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        {
            SetMessage("Facebook Auth Complete! Access Token: " + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString + "\nLogging into PlayFab...");

            /*
             * We proceed with making a call to PlayFab API. We pass in current Facebook AccessToken and let it create
             * and account using CreateAccount flag set to true. We also pass the callback for Success and Failure results
             */
            PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithFacebook(new LoginWithFacebookRequest { CreateAccount = true, AccessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString },
                OnPlayfabFacebookAuthComplete, OnPlayfabFacebookAuthFailed);
        }
        else
        {
            // If Facebook authentication failed, we stop the cycle with the message
            SetMessage("Facebook Auth Failed: " + result.Error + "\n" + result.RawResult, true);
        }
    }

    // When processing both results, we just set the message, explaining what's going on.
    private void OnPlayfabFacebookAuthComplete(LoginResult result)
    {
        SetMessage("PlayFab Facebook Auth Complete. Session ticket: " + result.SessionTicket);
    }

    private void OnPlayfabFacebookAuthFailed(PlayFabError error)
    {
        SetMessage("PlayFab Facebook Auth Failed: " + error.GenerateErrorReport(), true);
    }

    public void SetMessage(string message, bool error = false)
    {
        _message = message;
        if (error)
            Debug.LogError(_message);
        else
            Debug.Log(_message);
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        var style = new GUIStyle { fontSize = 40, normal = new GUIStyleState { textColor = Color.white }, alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter, wordWrap = true };
        var area = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
        GUI.Label(area, _message, style);
    }
}
```

Здесь код заточен под PlayFab. Там тоже везде зарегистрирован. Там же подключил Facebook и Facebook Insant Games. Пробовал и другие способы аутентификации и логина в fb, но что бы не использовал, всегда эта бесконечная загрузка на 0%. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Facebook SDK также интегрирован в Unity через их же официальный пакет. Если запускать скомпилированный проект под WEBGL, то все нормально, всплывает окно о входе в FB (Но ругается на то, что сайт не c https (логично, т.к. запуск идет с локалки)). Картинка с загрузкой в комментариях.

Comment: Разрешить в браузере попапы по идее можно. Способ зависит от браузера.

Comment: Попапы разрешены и тестировал на разных браузерах, ошибка не пропадает